# Navigation bar is not hiding in HostingViewController for iOS 16 if you build the app using Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, xcode13, ios16

I am using xcode 13.4.1 for build apps and also Hostingviewcontroller to host SwiftUI views. If I deploy the app in iOS 16, navigation bar is not hiding properly.

```
class HomeViewController: UIHostingController<HomeView> {
        

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

}
}
```